# I am looping through a worksheet with activex objects, I would like to set properties of the object

Tags: excel, vba, object

Trying to Change the background colors on option buttons as well will be doing checkbox

Here is code

```
Set sht = Worksheets(1)
Dim objX As OLEObject

For i = 1 To sht.OLEObjects.Count
    If TypeName(sht.OLEObjects(i).Object) = "OptionButton" Then
        sht.OLEObjects(i).Object = False
        sht.OLEObjects(i).BackColor = &HFFFFFF
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Sorry forgot I have missed a line after false sht.OLEObjects(i).BackColor = &HFFFFFF

Comment: I tried this line and I get a run time error 436, not supported

Comment: What is `.Object = False` supposed to be doing? You can't (shouldn't anyway) assign to `OLEObject.Object`.

Comment: Mathieu changing the value of the option button to false.

Answer (score 1):

`OLEObject.Object` is your ActiveX control. Problem is, its type is `Object`, so any member call against it is going to be late-bound, and that's annoying because what you want is code that is compile-time validated, and unless you're a masochist you'll want intellisense/autocompletion and parameter quick-info when you make member calls.

Declare a `MSForms.CheckBox` object variable (you want it fully-qualified, because just `As CheckBox` would resolve to `Excel.CheckBox`, and you don't want that), and since you're iterating an object collection, you want to use a `For Each` loop for this.

```
Dim oleObj As OLEObject
For Each oleObj In sht.OLEObjects
    If TypeOf oleObj.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then 
        Dim axCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox
        Set axCheckBox = oleObj.Object
        axCheckBox.Value = False
        axCheckBox.BackColor = vbWhite

    ElseIf TypeOf oleObj.Object Is MSForms.OptionButton Then
        Dim axOptionButton As MSForms.OptionButton
        Set axOptionButton = oleObj.Object
        axOptionButton.Value = False
        axOptionButton.BackColor = vbWhite

    End If
Next
```

Obviously that's a bit redundant, so we refactor and extract methods:

```
Private Sub FormatActiveXOptionButton(ByVal axControl As MSForms.OptionButton)
    axControl.Value = False
    axControl.BackColor = vbWhite
End Sub

Private Sub FormatActiveXCheckBox(ByVal axControl As MSForms.CheckBox)
    axControl.Value = False
    axControl.BackColor = vbWhite
End Sub
```

And now the loop can look like this:

```
Dim oleObj As OLEObject
For Each oleObj In sht.OLEObjects
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf oleObj.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox
            FormatActiveXCheckBox oleObj.Object

        Case TypeOf oleObj.Object Is MSForms.OptionButton
            FormatActiveXOptionButton oleObj.Object

    End Select
Next
```

Comment: And at some point in time you are going to find that ActiveX Controls will get wonky. Use Form Controls instead.

Comment: I am trying your code but it is not finding one checkbox on my worksheet. What am i missing

Comment: @MarkTash are you sure they're all ActiveX controls? Form controls wouldn't be in the OLEObjects collection

Comment: Yes I am, now just to make sure this is on a worksheet not a form

Comment: @MarkTash adding ActiveX controls on a worksheet will automatically add a reference to the MSForms type library in your VBA project - they're the exact same controls as those you use on a `UserForm` =)

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted to make sure. it still does not find any as  run through the code

Comment: this is set in a function, do I need to make reference to the worksheet or active.sheet

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you have a beautiful way of nudging toward better code writing practice <g>

Comment: Very Clean, but it still does not find the checkbox or the option buttons..  I even added a new active x control, made it red and ran the code. No change and no errors

Comment: @MarkTash ActiveX controls will be in the sheet's `OLEObjects` collection. If they're not in it, then they're not ActiveX controls. Make sure your sheet is active, and then type `?ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count` in the immediate pane (Ctrl+G). Does the number match the number of controls on the sheet?

Comment: when I add a msgbox before the case statement it says optonbutton1  MsgBox oleObj.Name

Comment: ?ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count = 22

Comment: And there *are* 22 controls on the sheet? Try replacing `vbWhite` with `vbRed` or `vbYellow` - still nothing? That makes no sense... place a breakpoint on the `Select Case` (F9), and when it's hit, press F8 to step through the code - does execution not enter any of the two `Case` blocks?

Comment: @MarkTash ugh - my bad, sorry for the untested air-code ...see edit (the `TypeOf oleObj` is `OLEObject`, ...needs to be `TypeOf oleObj.Object`).

Comment: Stepping through it never moves to the net line after the case statement. FormatActiveChexkbox is never touched

Comment: @MarkTash see previous comment / [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58757505/revisions)

Comment: that's it! thank you very much for your time and help. It is really appreciated.  You taught me allot .

Comment: Set Sht = Worksheets(1)

Dim oleObj As OLEObject

For Each oleObj In Sht.OLEObjects
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf oleObj.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox
            MsgBox oleObj.Name
            ResetActiveXCheckBox oleObj.Object

        Case TypeOf oleObj.Object Is MSForms.OptionButton
            ReSetActiveXOption oleObj.Object

    End Select
Next

Comment: Every time I run this the option buttons end up adjusting not the checkbox.. I do t understand why